# Is it possible to choose where the pipe output is inserted into Elixir function args?

Tags: list, functional-programming, pipeline, elixir

Consider a (smelly, non-idiomatic) function like the below:

```
def update_2d(array, inds, val) do
    [first_coord, second_coord] = inds

    new_arr = List.update_at(array, second_coord, fn(y) ->
      List.update_at(Enum.at(array, second_coord),
        first_coord, fn(x) -> val end) end)
end
```

This function will take in a list of lists, a list of two indices, and a value to insert within the list of lists at the location specified by the indices.

As a first step to making this more Elixir-ey, I start laying pipe:

```
array 
  |> Enum.at(second_coord) 
  |> List.update_at(first_coord, fn(x) -> val end)
```

That gets me most of the way there, but **how do I pipe that output into the anonymous function of the last `List.update_at` call?** I can nest it within the original call, but that seems like giving up:

```
List.update_at(array, second_coord, fn(y) -> 
  array 
  |> Enum.at(second_coord) 
  |> List.update_at(first_coord, fn(x) -> val end) 
end)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply bind to a variable to capture your first result and then replace it in the second `List.update_at/3` call

```
def update_2d(array, inds = [first_coord, second_coord], val) do
  updated =
    array
    |> Enum.at(second_coord) 
    |> List.update_at(first_coord, fn(x) -> val end)

    List.update_at(array, second_coord, fn(x) -> updated end)
end
```

You can also use the [capture](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#&/1) operator to do this:

```
  def update_2d(array, inds = [first_coord, second_coord], val), do:    
    array
    |> Enum.at(second_coord) 
    |> List.update_at(first_coord, fn(x) -> val end)
    |> (&(List.update_at(array, second_coord, fn(y) -> &1 end))).()
```

I find using a variable much more readable, but the option is there.

Comment: Hahaha, that's true. I *am* trying to be so clever with the above.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander I have also provided a way to do it without a temporary variable.

Comment: Ah! I was trying something like that but I was not capturing the whole call.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just create a private function that receives the arguments in the proper order and then performs the call. :)

Comment: What is worth noting about the capture method is that it frees you from coming up with a name (for a function or a temp variable).
But personally I usually tend to use the "private function that receives the arguments" - that José mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

As of Elixir 1.12, there is the `then\2`. See the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#then/2)

```
|> then(fn x -> x * 2 end)
    
|> then(fn x -> Enum.drop(["a", "b", "c"], x) end)
["b", "c"]
```

Answer (score -2):

How about:

```
{:foo, :bar} |> elem(1) |> Enum.Map(fn x -> x end)
```

Seems easier.